Add a line count in specific format in the text file
I am trying to export a selected range to a TXT file. I found the code below and converted to my TXT needs. How/where can I add a line count function at the end of the document output? (The total line count needs to include the count of the input and not just the exported lines.)
The count needs to be in a specific format. My Excel formula is currently picking it up with this formula (edited to show where count is needed):
=CONCAT(99,REPT(0,9-LEN(LINE COUNT)),LINE COUNT,REPT(" ",289))

Sub SaveSelectionAsTextFile()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim saveFileName As String
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Set the workbook and worksheet variables
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("CKO Template") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your actual sheet name
    
    ' Prompt user to select the range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to export:", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if user canceled the selection
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Prompt user for save location and filename
    savePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="TXT Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    
    ' Check if user canceled the save dialog
    If savePath = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Get the file name from the full path
    saveFileName = Dir(savePath)
    
    ' Export the range to TXT
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim file As Object
        Set file = .CreateTextFile(savePath, True)
        
        Dim row As Range
        For Each row In rng.Rows
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                file.Write cell.Value & ","
            Next cell
            file.WriteLine
                Next row
        
        file.Close
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Selected range exported to TXT successfully."
End Sub


What do you mean by the total line count also needs to include the count of the input and not just the exported lines

When I select the range to be exported and if that count of lines is i.e 900, the count total line needs to be added into the total lines so it would say 901 - that may just be a given but added that detail just in case

Maybe a silly question but can I build this into the current output or do I need to create a new VBA entirely and pull in the file path? (sorry very new to this)

In VBA you can do something like this:
'...
Dim lc As Long
'...
lc = rng.Rows.Count + 1
'... write range content
file.WriteLine "99" & Format(lc, String(9, "0")) & String(289, " ")
'...


nicely done :-)
